# angular multi select dropdown not displaying value

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1" style="margin-left: -5%;">
                    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="product" 
                                    selected-model="selectedproductmodel"
                                    extra-settings="productsettings"
                                    translation-texts="example5customTexts">  
</div>
```

controller code here

```
 $scope.selectedproductmodel = [];    
         $scope.productsettings = {
                    scrollableHeight: '200px',
                    scrollable: true,
                    enableSearch: true
                };
```

i am getting values in single dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedproduct"  ng-options="option as option.product_name for option in product"><option></option></select>
```

[i am not getting the values in dropdown.please someone help me to solve this.Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf6OO.png)

Comment: Please copy and past your dropdown div and your controller so we can see what the issue is

Comment: added code for controller and div

Comment: Please try to formulate your question correctly. We have no idea which directive you're using for your multiselect, we have no idea what controller you're talking about (the one from your directive, or from your scope where the select is called). Please have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where are your products?

Comment: i am getting product list from DB and getting values in console log in controller .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to help you when you dont give us more directions.
We need to know what exactly is the problem including your variables and html, not a general not working issue.

I would suggest you try the simple example and see if it works.
If it does, change the variable names to yours. if it works add the other stuff.
If not, you can post your findings: "with ... it fails".

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>

$scope.example1model = []; 
$scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
```